# Value in cx_Oracle.OBJECT missing

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, object-type, instantclient

I have a custom type in oracle (lro_dummy). I have also a procedure. I looks like this:

```
procedure dummyLro
(
    i_dummy         in  lro_dummy,
    o_dummy         out lro_dummy
)is
begin
    o_dummy := lro_dummy('asdf');
end dummyLro;
```

Now I want to call this procedure from python with cx_Oracle. This looks like this:

```
def test(db_con):
  cur = db_con.cursor()
  try:
    procedure_params = {}
    procedure_params["i_dummy"] = cur.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT, typename="lro_dummy")
    procedure_params["o_dummy"] = cur.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT, typename="lro_dummy")

    cur.callproc("test.dummyLro", [], procedure_params)
```

After that `o_dummy` has a value because

```
str(procedures_params["o_dummy"])
```

returns

```
'<cx_Oracle.OBJECT with value <cx_Oracle.Object ???.LRO_DUMMY at 0x10492c9c0>>'
```

But I can not access my attribute. The attribute are listed in

```
procedure_params["o_dummy"].type.attributes
```

But I can not find the value in

```
procedure_params["o_dummy"]
```

What did I wrong?

I am using `Python 3.6`, `cx_Oracle 5.3`, `InstantClient 11.2`, `Oracle-Server 11`

Comment: What are the attributes listed in procedure_params["o_dummy"].type.attributes?

Comment: It returns an array of `cx_Oracle.ObjectAttribute DUMMY` with one item. The attribute `name` has the value `DUMMY`

Comment: So you should be able to access it via procedure_params["o_dummy"].DUMMY?

Comment: I know that it should work like this. But I got no attribute called `DUMMY`. The only attributes I have are `bufferSize`, `inconverter`, `numElements`, `outconverter`, `size` and `type`. Does it work only with special oracle-databases? Is my type (lro_dummy) incorrect?

Comment: Even if I try to create a new object of `lro_dummy` with `db_con.gettype("lro_dummy").newobject()` the only attribute I get is `type`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. According to the "docs"(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/prez-stored-proc-084100.html) it should work the way you did it, but it did not work for me. As far as I can see, the params passed in to the proc are not mutated. Instead new objects are returned.  This worked for me:

```
i_dummy = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT, typename='lro_dummy')
o_dummy = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.OBJECT, typename='lro_dummy')
[something, returned_o_dummy] = cur.callproc("test.dummyLro", [], [i_dummy, o_dummy])
print(returned_o_dummy.DUMMY)
```